# Calling Java from R with System2 and Status 127

Tags: java, r, rstudio, system2

I am using RStudio on Windows.

```
system2("java C:/myClass", args = as.character(myVector))
Warning message:
running command '"java C:/myClass" 1 1 1' had status 127
```

From my understanding, this should mean that the command prompt is not able to recognise my call to a Java class file (which, however, should work).

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run the same line in command prompt?

Comment: It works without problem.